# Angular ui calendar shows strange behaviour when puling data

Tags: angularjs, request, freeze

I have the following issue (which is similar to another post from mine): While pulling data from my db (locally) the screen is freezed but not during the request time (select and all that stuff) but when looping the return data.

To be more clear: If you want to update your calendar, I figure that you cannot do this:

```
$scope.turnosConversion = [];
$scope.turnosConversion = ... // Returned Data
```

But you have to do something like this:

```
while($scope.turnosConversion.length !== 0)
{
    $scope.turnosConversion.splice(0,1);
}
```

To keep the the origina reference array and then to something like this...

```
for(var a = 0; a < turnos.length; a++)
{
                                                $scope.turnosServicio.push(turnos[a]);
                                            }
```

Where "turnos" is the array object...

The thing is that that the data is returned really quick but when I make the loop to push the events, the screen gets hanged or freezed... And the curious thing is that this happens with mozilla firefox but not with chrome...

The thing is that when data is returned, the concat array function doesn't work... Let say I do this:

```
$scope.turnosConversion.concat(turnos);
```

This is giving a headache... I woud like to achieve the same behaviour as in chrome, where it works really fast... Hope there is a chance... Thankx

P.D.: I have tried as other said to put a setimeout function while looping but it's strange how the array is filled...

Comment: When working with Firefox and AngularJS make sure Firebug is disabled. Care: Firebug can be enabled even when the window is not visible.

Comment: Christopher. Thank you for your answer... I'm going by bus to my mother's house; I'll be checking that as soon as I arrive... Hopes this helps... As this is freaking me out...

Comment: Christopher. I have doubts If I am disabling firebug... I have firebug 42 !. Do you mean that If I disable firebug it will stop analyzing the page the freeze will go out?

Comment: There can be situations where Firebug negatively influences the performance of AngularJS applications. I cannot say if this solves your freezes but at least we can rule out one possible problem. If this does not help, try to provide a plunker where the problem is reproducible.